# Which version of elementary OS can I install?

Tags: system-installation

I have an older Sony PC with the following hardware:

- Intel Core2Duo E7200 CPU
- 2GB RAM
- 320GB HDD

Which version of elementary OS will work well on this computer?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run 5.1.3 Hera.

Here are the specs you need:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- 1024×768 display

https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation

Answer (score 0):

- *Please make your title clearer to address your problem. A better title would’ve been “I’m running on a low-spec PC, should I downgrade my version of Elementary OS?”*

Yes — for the most part.
You should be able to run Elementary OS with 2 GBs of RAM but —— as per the website —— 4 GB is recommended for comfortable usage of Elementary OS

However, you should add more detail because there is one thing I can’t answer —— graphics card compatibility. You need to be able to run at least 720p display resolution with your graphics card for Elementary OS to function properly/look proper ([also mentioned on the website](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation)) and you need a display that can support that resolution